# add an onChange function to this dynamically populated select field to echo result to a textfield

Tags: php

I checked the boards and Googled for this code but couldn't find anything.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have worked through a tutorial that queries a database for a car model based on the car make.  In the code, the car make is hardcoded to the select while the car model is dynamic.  Here's the first part of the code:

```
    <?php 
    require_once("Connections/xxx.php"); // database connection

    $make = $_POST['make'];


    if ($make){
    $query= sprintf("SELECT * FROM car_model where car_model_id='$make'");
    $result = @mysql_query($query); 
    $rowModel = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }
    ?>
```

Here's the select hard code:

```
<select name="make" onChange="document.forms[0].submit()">
<option value="">Select Make</option>
<option value="1" <?php if(!(strcmp(1, $make))){echo "selected";}?>>Alfa Romeo</option>
<option value="2" <?php if(!(strcmp(2, $make))){echo "selected";}?>>Audi</option>
<option value="3" <?php if(!(strcmp(3, $make))){echo "selected";}?>>BMW</option>
<option value="4" <?php if(!(strcmp(4, $make))){echo "selected";}?>>Citroen</option>
```

And this is the dynamically populated select:

```
 <select name="model">
<option value="">Select Model</option>
<?php do {  ?>
<option value="<?php echo $rowModel['car_model_id']; ?>"><?php echo $rowModel['car_model']; ?></option>
<?php  }while ($rowModel = mysql_fetch_array($result));  ?>
```

I would like to add an onChange function to this dynamically populated select field to echo result to a textfield and I have tried many combinations but haven't been able to figure this out.  Thank you

Comment: you should use unobtrusive javascript and then you don't have to worry about fitting it in with this other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't like my jquery version, which I still feel is a better answer here the javascript way which I'm sure is not going to be supported in every browser and be very buggy (thus the reason most people use jquery)

```
<select name="model" onchange="update_textbox()" id="model">
    <option value="">Select Model</option>
    <?php while ($rowModel = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rowModel['car_model_id']; ?>">
       <?php echo $rowModel['car_model']; ?>
      </option>
    <?php  } ?>
</select>
<input type="text" id="model_text">
<script>
 function update_textbox(){
  var selectbox = document.getElementById('model');
  var model = selectbox[selectbox.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById('model_text').value=model ;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I respect your opinion because you have the experience.  I'll learn jquery in class next year. 

Thanks for your answer but there is still a problem. The revised script seems to be updating the car_model_id instead of the car model.

Comment: There I've changed it to put the text of the option box in the text box instead of putting the value.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, you have answered my original question very well.  Since you suggest jquery, what would that code look like and would I need to be concerned about the sql injection using jquery?

Comment: I have modified my other answer to show the jquery way to do the same thing. Neither one of them have sql injection as there isn't any sql in the code. This line is the one that needs to be fixed for sql injection: $query= sprintf("SELECT * FROM car_model where car_model_id='$make'"); should be $query= sprintf("SELECT * FROM car_model where car_model_id='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($make));

Answer (score 0):

Your query is exposed to sql injection escape your input before constructing query or use prepared queries (use of php pdo is recommended)

```
<select name="model">
    <option value="">Select Model</option>
    <?php while ($rowModel = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rowModel['car_model_id']; ?>" onChange="textfield(this.value)" ><?php echo $rowModel['car_model']; ?></option>
    <?php  } ?>
<script>
function textfield(val)
{
  document.getElementById('your_text_filed_id').value=val;
}

<script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  This is new for me and a tutorial, so I will need to read more on sql injection and how to escape query.  For now, do you know how to get the $rowModel into a textfield and not an alert? Thanks

Comment: I think it would be very helpful to have a feature that allows a user to mark responses as non applicable and then give the user the ability to resubmit the question with 0 responses, so that others might attempt to answer the question correctly. I submitted what I believed to be a simple question and got back two answers, one did not work, the other was a suggestion to use another process but did not even address my original response. Not being ungrateful here, just seems like such a waste of time. Can this be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jquery instead of putting the javascript inline. That way the code can be reused.

```
<select name="model">
    <option value="">Select Model</option>
    <?php while ($rowModel = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){  ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $rowModel['car_model_id']; ?>">
       <?php echo $rowModel['car_model']; ?>
      </option>
    <?php  } ?>
</select>
<input type="text" id="model_text">
```

Here is the javascript that should be put into a common js file.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('select[name="model"]').change(function(){
       $('#model_text').val($(this).text());
     });
  });
</script>
```

I would also recommend like Arun Killu said to do something to not have sql injection. Putting a variable into the sql without cleaning it first is never a good idea. Even if currently the user doesn't have access to change it.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer.  This is new for me and a tutorial.  I will be taking a jquery class next year, but for now I have no idea on how to proceed with what you have provided. Thanks

Comment: I think it would be very helpful to have a feature that allows a user to mark responses as non applicable and then give the user the ability to resubmit the question with 0 responses, so that others might attempt to answer the question correctly.

I submitted what I believed to be a simple question and got back two answers, one did not work, the other was a suggestion to use another process but did not even address my original response.  Not being ungrateful here, just seems like such a waste of time.

Can this be done?

Thanks

Comment: The reason I suggested jquery is not cause I like it or whatever it's cause it actually makes what you are trying to do much easier. If you want to do it without jquery. Add an onchange attribute to the select and tie it to a function.